# Где скачать Qt SDK под свободной лицензией для Win 7

Tags: qt

Где скачать Qt SDK под свободной лицензией для Win 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы имеете в виду библиотеки?

Конечно, на офсайте: http://qt-project.org/downloads

> Qt is available under GPL v3, LGPL v2 and a [commercial license](http://qt.digia.com/download).

Или вы имеете в виду [Nokia](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Qt_SDK) [SDK](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/da8df288-e615-443d-be5c-00c8a72435f8/Qt_SDK.html)? (Вам нужен будет аккаунт разработчика.)

Comment: Думаю, все гораздо проще - раньше был один большой пакет QtSdk, а теперь нужно отдельно скачать minGW (или майкросовтовскую студию), отдельно qtcreator и отдельно саму библиотеку, а большого пакета больше нет.

Comment: эх... понятно. попробую.